# Embed named router outlet with MatDialog in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, router-outlet

I want to a routing system inside a MatDialog component which can be open anywhere in my app.

**Explanation**

So I'm on `/tata`, I open the dialog on tab 2. So I want a specific URL. When I copy/past it, the dialog is opened on tab 2 with the context on background `/tata`

**Try**

In app.component.html, add a `<router-outlet name="dialog"></router-outlet>`

In my routes declaration :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'mainDialog', 
    outlet: 'dialog',
    component: DialogOpenerComponent, 
    data: { dialog: MainDialogComponent }, 
    children: [
    { 
        path: 'dialogSubTab', 
        component: MainDialogSubTabComponent, 
        outlet: 'dialog-sub-tab' }
    ]}
];
```

`DialogOpenerComponent` makes a open dialog call with `MainDialogComponent` as the component.

When I call `this.router.navigate([{outlets: { 'dialog': 'mainDialog' }}]);` the main dialog is opened.

But after opening `MainDialogComponent`, how can I route to other child routes?

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem? I'm facing the same issue and I can't find anything to solve this :(

Comment: you mean navigate to other routes within the dialog itself?